# Best math font with Times New Roman in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, times

I compile my document with the following commands in the header:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

which works fine.  What is the "best" math font that will match the text in the body, and what are the commands to set up this font?  I tried using:

```
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```

but

1. I think newtxmath is a Times clone, not a Times New Roman clone,
2. I get a lot of "size substitutions" errors when I compile my document with XeLaTeX.

Comment: Try `TeX Gyre Termes Math`.

Comment: @DG' Isn't Termes also a clone of Times rather than of TNR?

Comment: Xits is supposed to be Times-like, also. I'm not sure what you will find a match for TNR *as opposed to* Times.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure what's supposed to be *best*. The following methods work *well*, though.

For the Times (New) Roman *text* font, you could choose (via `\setmainfont`)

- `Times New Roman`
- `XITS`
- `TeX Gyre Termes`
- `Stix Two Text` (see http://stixfonts.org/ for more information)

For a Times (New) Roman-like math font, first load the `unicode-math` package and then load (via `\setmathfont`)

- `XITS Math`
- `TeX Gyre Termes Math`
- `Stix Two Math`.

Alternatively, just use

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

---

*First Addendum*: A personal comment on the mostly minuscule differences between `Times` (aka `Times Roman`) and `Times New Roman`. To the best of my knowledge, there are *only two* readily-noticeable differences among the two fonts when using Latin letters (more differences occur with Greek letters):

- the *italic* lowercase letter `z`: it's "swashy" with Times Roman, but non-swashy with Times New Roman; and
- the `%` symbol, in both upright and italic mode: the first, i.e., upper "0" symbol and the solidus (aka slash symbol) are *not connected* with Times New Roman, but they are connected with Times Roman.

[image]

Would you -- or anyone else who's not a rather serious font afficionado -- ever take note of these differences and say, "tut, tut, why is this document using `Times` if it should be using `Times New Roman`? (Some even less readily visible differences between the two fonts are listed on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_New_Roman#Times_Roman_and_Times_New_Roman).)

---

*Second Addendum*: If you happen to have access to the commercial `MathTime Professional II` ("`mtpro2`") Times-like math font package and wish to use under either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you should (a) load it *before* loading `fontspec`, (b) load the `fontspec` package with the option `no-math`, and (c) *not* load the `unicode-math` package at all. I.e., the relevant part of your document's preamble should look roughly like this:

```
\usepackage{mtpro2} % or: \usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
%% load 'fontspec' only if we are running either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}
\ifxetex       \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\else\ifluatex \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\fi\fi
\usepackage[osf]{newtxtext} % or some other suitable Times-like text font
```

---

Finally, here's the code needed to produce the little table shown above; compile it with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. (Of course, you will need to have access to the fonts `Myriad Pro`, `Times`, and `Times New Roman` in order to be able to compile it.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Myriad Pro}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{``Times''-like font}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
                  & Times & Times New Roman \\
\midrule
Text-italic ``z'' & \setmainfont{Times}[ItalicFont={Times Italic}] \textit{z}
                  & \setmainfont{Times New Roman} \textit{z}\\   
Percent symbol    & \setmainfont{Times} \% 
                  & \setmainfont{Times New Roman} \% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the XITS font, thanks.  Indeed, at this point I don't really care about the differences in math between Times and Times New Roman.

Comment: i would use `Tex Gyre Termes` as main font in the first place. Or rather not use it. I don't like it at all. It's to narrow, very hard to reed because lines contain a lot of letters. Try a broader font like Palating (Tex Gyre Pagella). I really like EB Garamond, but it's not complete yet and there will maybe never be a math font.

Comment: Palatino of course

Comment: @MaxNoe - Since the question was about a *math font* to go with Times (or Times New Roman...), what are you trying to achieve by suggesting a switch to either Palatino or EB Garamond as the *text font* ?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the standard choice among publishers for a Times compatible math font is Math Time Professional 2: http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html. You have to pay for the full version but a free "lite" version is also available (and will be sufficient for most documents.)